# 12.04.5 installed without my knowledge

Tags: upgrade

I went right from 12.04.4 to 12.04.5 today, which is alright, but unexpected.  Could someone please explain how this happened, and why?

Comment: Did you accept an upgrade from the Software Updater module?

Comment: I have been watching for the upgrade to 14.04.1 to appear in the update manager, so, no, I did not see nor accept an upgrade.  Fair question, though!

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.04.5 is a compendium of various fixes and patches since 12.04.4 - since you have been keeping your system up-to-date, and you have all of the fixes, your system reports you being at the level of 12.04.5

Comment: Ok, thanks for you comment.  I was thinking we get notices for incremental step-ups like 12.04.1-12.04-2 etc.  How can I not pick up on these things?  I still would like to see 14.04.1 show up however.  This was released July 24.  Impatience rules.

Comment: I'm not sure how that will work for you - My system reports 14.04.1 (although I installed 14.04 and upgraded slowly) - I think you need to force the upgrade to 14 before you will see what you are looking for.